# How to separate the message bit and parity bit of a block code given only the parity check matrix H?

Tags: coding-theory

[image: Parity check matrix]

I really want to know how can we know if the code coming from this parity check matrix is systematic or not ?

Also, is there anyway to know the encoding rule (the order of which the message bit and parity bit are arranged) ?

For example
m1 m2 m3 m4 p1 p2 p3 or m1 m2 p1 m3 p2 p3 m4 ?

I really think that I should try to put it back into a corresponding generator matrix by using some row and column operation but  swapping column of H around would result in a completely different set of code from the original H. In some sense I have a feeling that some how I should keep track of the column permutation

Comment: No, there are several choices for which bits are the message bits (or information bits) and which are the parity check bits. The easiest way is from the generator matrix, a choice of four independent columns will give four entries that can be used as the information set. (you can't get the generator matrix from row and column operations)

Comment: Oh thank you ~!